# Form Responses Changing Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to make it so that when you submit my form - if you type 'Martin' in first name, 'Neuhard' in last name, and select 'Binghamton University' in the dropdown it changes the background green and pops up a pitcure of binghamton university. It works if i use || but not when i use &&.

Also i want to make it so that if the two email field aren't the same then alert('error')

I've been trying for hours and cannot figure it out. the jsfiddle is below

http://jsfiddle.net/esaunde1/ngjo8aoq/

HTML

```
        <div class="container" id='contact'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="well well-sm">
              <form class="form-horizontal" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
              <fieldset>
                <legend class="text-center">Get in touch!</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="name">First Name</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your first name" data-    trigger="manual" data-content="Can only contain letters!" class=" form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" type="text" required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Your last name" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Can only contain letters!" class="name form-control" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z]+">
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="email">E-mail Address</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?" class="email form-control" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid e-mail address" type="text" email required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="emailCheck">E-mail Address</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="emailCheck" name="emailCheck" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?" class="email form-control" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid e-mail address" type="text" email required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="email">Your Phone Number</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="What is your phone number?" class="form-control phone" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid phone number" type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-xs-4 control-label'>What school do you go to?</label>
                    <div class='col-xs-8'>
                        <select class="form-control" id='dropdown'>
                          <option>Select One</option>
                          <option>The College of NJ</option>
                          <option>Rutgers University</option>
                          <option>Columbia University</option>
                          <option value="bing">Binghamton University</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Check Form" onClick='return valid()'>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function valid(){   

var name = document.getElementById('name');
var lname = document.getElementById('lame');
var home = document.getElementById('home');

    if (name.value == 'Martin' && lname.value == 'Neuhard' && ){
        $('#home').addClass('green');
        $('#contact').addClass('image');

        }
    else if (document.getElementById('first').value == 'martin'){
        alert('thats our profs name!')
    }
    else return false;
```

}

Comment: Do you have CSS you can add to the fiddle? Hard to test if none of the conditional styles apply :-)

Comment: You've got a typo `document.getElementById('lame')` should be `document.getElementById('lname')`. This would break your `if` statement.

Comment: jsfiddle has been updated http://jsfiddle.net/esaunde1/ngjo8aoq/2/ and thank you! that solves one problem...

Comment: One more error -else if (document.getElementById('first').value == 'martin'){ --->here it should not be 'first', it should be 'name'

Comment: how about a jquery solution?

Comment: jquery is fine. the real question is how do i change the value depending on if the user selects binghamotn from the dropdown

Comment: and how can i pop up an error if the two emails arent the same

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check-btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $('form');
        var fName = $('#name', $form).val();
        var lName = $('#lname', $form).val();
        var school = $('#dropdown', $form).val();
        if(fName == 'Martin' && lName == 'Neuhard' && school == 'bing'){
            //do something here
            $('#contact').addClass('green');
        }
        else if(fName == 'martin'){
            alert('thats our profs name!')
        }

        //if the 2 emails are not the same
        var email = $('#email', $form).val();
        var repeatEmail = $('#emailCheck', $form).val();
        if(email != repeatEmail){
            alert('Email does not match!');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngjo8aoq/3/

Comment: I have added an id for the check button, and removed the onclick attr. Also make sure you are including jquery with a <script> tag

Comment: Make sure the HTML is the same and that you have the new css rules for .green { background-color: green; }

Comment: it says $ is not defined but i was using a little jquery before so ik its working

Comment: try changing $(document).ready(function () to jQuery(document).ready(function ($)

Comment: You don't have jquery loaded properly. figure this out, I can't help you with your source code on your server :)